Charge Renormalization in Abelian Gauge Theory under General Gauge Fixing Conditions
In scalar QED or fermionic QED, the relationship between bare quantities (subscript "B") and renormalized quantities is given by
$$
\begin{aligned}
A^\mu_B &= \sqrt{Z_A} A^\mu\,, \quad \psi_B = \sqrt{Z_\psi} \psi\,, \quad \phi_B = \sqrt{Z_\phi} \phi\,, \\
m_B &= Z_m m\,, \quad e_B = \frac{Z_e}{\sqrt{Z_A}} e\,, \quad c_B = \sqrt{Z_c} c\,.
\end{aligned}
$$
We assume that a regularization compatible with gauge symmetry is used. If the gauge fixing term is
$$
\mathcal{L}_{\rm gf} = -\frac{1}{\xi} (\partial \cdot A)^2\,,
$$
then it can be shown that the Ward identity holds, and from this it can be proven that $Z_e = 1$, which implies $e_B A^\mu_B = e A^\mu$. On the other hand, in non-Abelian gauge theory, $Z_g$ in $g_B = Z_g Z_A^{-1/2} g$ is not equal to $1$, thus the property $Z_e = 1$ is unique to Abelian gauge theory.
What I am curious about is, under general gauge fixing conditions, such as $R_\xi$ gauge or other gauge fixing conditions, does $Z_e = 1$ still hold? If $Z_e=1$ still holds, then how to prove it?
